# How to read image from internal memory in android?

Tags: android

this screen shot of my internal memory storage which i save image already.
i want to read image in image view. so how to get path of image or how can i read image from internal memory?
please help me..
i tried some code but its not working:-

```
 FileInputStream fis;
        String filePath = activity.getFilesDir().getPath();
         String path = data.get(position).get("product_image");
         fis = openFileInput(filePath+"/broccolicasserole.jpg");
         Bitmap      bitmapA = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
         producticon.setImageBitmap(bitmapA);
```

image name is get from database like :-data.get(position).get("product_image");
also try this code also:-

```
  >  String filePath = activity.getFilesDir().getPath();
   File filePath1 =   imageLoader.DisplayImage(filePath+data.get(position).get("product_image"), producticon);
```

[image: this is my internal memory which i save that image already]

Comment: you want to get image from gallery basically?

Comment: where you are saving your image path in your app? @tej

Comment: @mono :- yes in my internal storage. please check screen shot of DDMS

Comment: @amarbir Singh:- no.. i want image to display in list view at imageview

Comment: which image that you clicked?? Then get the path of the image where you are saving.

Comment: I see in your other comments, you get an error: `/data/data/com.wtow.restaurant/app_imageDir/Restaurant/broccolicasserole.jpg` look in your image in your question. Your path should be `/data/data/com.wtow.restaurant/app_files/Restaurant/broccolicasserole.jpg`

Comment: @Knossos :- thank brother. really i miss that thing. answer that i will make up sure.

Comment: hey i have one problem still. error geting out of memory when i load image

Comment: Search for that on Stackoverflow. It is heavily documented. Android has well known problems with loading images. Mostly due to memory restrictions on Apps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
private String readFileFromInternalStorage(){
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);

    //path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/dirName
    File directory = cw.getDir("dirName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);          
    File mypath=new File(directory,"imagename.jpg");

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(mypath.toString()));
}
```

> Code isn't tested. Or Try Below!

```
private void setImage(String imgPath)
{

    try {
        File f=new File(imgPath, "imgName.jpg");
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        img.setImageBitmap(b);
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: just try both code. not got image error geting like:- 07-01 03:35:54.131: W/System.err(6169): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.wtow.restaurant/app_imageDir/Restaurant/broccolicasserole.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-01 03:35:54.131: W/System.err(6169):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
07-01 03:35:54.131: W/System.err(6169):  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)

Comment: where you installed the app,in external memory or internal ?

Comment: Try to get the path according to the storage medium.

Comment: but now again error of out of memory.. how can i solve that

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861929/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-android/29863404#29863404

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82073/discussion-between-tej-shah-and-anoop-m).

Answer (score 1):

Try like this it will Work ,

```
ImageView  picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);  

       String pic = result.getString(YourImagepathname);//get path of your image
        Bitmap yourSelectedImage1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pic);
       picture.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage1);
```

Comment: not image display error of log cat is :- Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.wtow.restaurant/app_imageDir/Restaurant/broccolicasserole.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: so your image saved in local memory of application, Then path saved in Local Database right?

Comment: problem in your image Path directory saving in your database

Comment: /data/data/com.wtow.restaurant/app_files/Restaurant/broccolicasserole.jpg- this is your Correct path of a image. you are saving as a  /data/data/com.wtow.restaurant/app_imageDir/Restaurant/broccolicasserole.jpg

Comment: but now again error of out of memory.. how can i solve that